# How to print and remove integers from a file on computer

Tags: java, integer

I am trying to read a file from my computer, and have the system print out the file only containing the letters, and not printing the numbers. I have other functions in my code already so please look near the bottom where I am stuck with arraylist. How do I ignore the integers when printing?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    ArrayList <String> myFileLines = new ArrayList <String>();

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/wolftrek/Downloads/example.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            myFileLines.add(sCurrentLine);

            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {

            if (reader != null)reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < myFileLines.size(); i++) {
        if (myFileLines.get(i).contains("example word")) {
            System.out.println(myFileLines.get(i));
        }
    }

    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    String enteredString = "";

    System.out.println("Please enter the characters to search for: ");
    enteredString = myScanner.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < myFileLines.size(); i++) {
        if (myFileLines.get(i).contains(enteredString)) {
            System.out.println(myFileLines.get(i));
        }
    }

    ArrayList<String> input = myFileLines;
    String extract = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
    System.out.println(extract);


}
}
```

Comment: this `replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "")` is not working?, can you post the input and output

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method replaceAll(UnaryOperator<String>) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

 at BufferedReaderExample.main(BufferedReaderExample.java:60)


This is the error message I am getting when I try to run it. The error Eclipse is telling me is "String extract = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "");" is that "the method replaceAll(UnaryOperator<String>) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"

Comment: `input.replaceAll(s -> s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", ""));`  Also, `input` is *not* a copy of `myFileLInes`.  Also, the regex does not ignore integers as the question suggests, it keeps only letters a-z or A-Z (so other characters besides integers would also be replaced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is you are applying replaceAll on a list and also the regex is not correct. Something like below will do the job. I am not clear if that's what you want though.

```
    ArrayList<String> input = myFileLines;
    for (String e : input) {
        String extract = e.replaceAll("\\d+", "");
        System.out.println(extract);
    }
```